# How can I use data repeater correctly here

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I want to repeat the same design for every employee I have in the database. It is like an attendance sheet. I want it as the following, the employee's picture, then next to it, the employee's name then a DropDown menu with name of the projects, then two buttons: either present or absent.

And here is my code so far:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  _connection.Open();
  OdbcCommand getempos = new OdbcCommand("SELECT ID, filepth from empos ", _connection);
  OdbcDataReader loopempos = getempos.ExecuteReader();

  while (loopempos.Read())
  {
    OdbcCommand findempros = new OdbcCommand("SELECT p.projName from projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname WHERE a.employeeID LIKE '" + loopempos["ID"].ToString() + "'", _connection);
    OdbcDataReader readit = findempros.ExecuteReader();

    while (readit.Read())
    {
      DropDownList mydblist = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
      mydblist.Items.Add(readit["projName"].ToString());
    }

  }
  _connection.Close();
}
```

The issue here is that DropDown menu doesn't get the projects the employee assigned to. Second, I can't distinguish between buttons. I mean when a user clicks on the present or absent button, I don't know which employee these buttons refers to. I'm not quite sure if this is the best way to do what I want to do. Other thoughts would be appreciated.

I'm using repeater because I need the same pattern repeated for every employee and I believe repeater is the best option here.

Comment: You may look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc424995%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) one.

Comment: You should use parameters instead of concatenating your SQL to avoid SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mostly on the right track, I think.  I'm assuming that your repeater is being populated with a query containing a record for each employee you want to display.

For there, you've got a couple of issues:

1. Buttons.  Set their "CommandArgument" to the unique key (database ID, whatever) of the record during the bind.  Just use ' />
2. For the project list, if looks like you're looping through every employee record inside of the repeater's ItemDataBound event, which is probably not what you want.  The repeater produces a fixed bit of markup for each record in a given set of data.  The ItemCreated event is fired as each repeater item is created, one RepeaterItem for each employee assuming that's the data set that you're binding the repeater itself to.  I have no idea how you are initially binding the data, so the line where you grab e.Item.DataItem in the code below might have to change.  Also, the part where I have data.ID will be very dependent on how you're populating the repeater in the first place.  This was just intended to get you on the right track.
3. Also, I'm not sure how much control you might have over you data structure, but if your unique key on these records requires you to use a LIKE comparison in your WHERE condition, you should reevaluate that structure, if possible.  Using something like LIKE or UPPER/LOWER in the WHERE condition of your SQL will prevent the use of indexes and could make this query run slowly.
4. Finally, just to point it out, you should at least use a Try-Finally block to ensure that your database connection gets closed.

   ```
   protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
   {
       _connection.Open();
       try
       {
           DataItemTypeName data = (DataItemTypeName)e.Item.DataItem;
           if (data == null)
               // This is more of a debugging check, since I'm a little in the dark about data types and such here.
               throw new Exception("No data.");

           OdbcCommand findempros = new OdbcCommand("SELECT p.projName from projects p INNER JOIN assigns a ON p.projID = a.projname WHERE a.employeeID LIKE '" + data.ID + "'", _connection);
           OdbcDataReader readit = findempros.ExecuteReader();

           while (readit.Read())
           {
               DropDownList mydblist = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
               mydblist.Items.Add(readit["projName"].ToString());
           }
       }
       finally
       { _connection.Close(); }
   }
   ```